# How do you inverse a "locate" command. Ex. Show everything except X

Tags: locate

when doing a locate to find a specific file, it shows alot of stuff, but is there a way to inverse what is shown? Ex. locate anything that has the word drupal in it, but don't show anything from the home directory.

Comment: I don't think locate command itself has any option for inverse but you can always pipe you output and filter out what you don;'t want to see with `grep -v` command using or use `find . -type -f not -name "pattern"'

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I do what @Raza suggests all the time.  For example, let's say I want to find all font-related files *not* sitting in `~/installations/` waiting to be installed.

```
locate font | grep -v installations
```

Oops, I forgot that will match a lot of things in `$HOME/.cache` and `$HOME/.config`.

```
locate font | grep -v $HOME
```

Now to get rid of man pages, locale stuff, icons, ...

```
locate font | grep -v -e $HOME -e icons -e /man/ -e /locale/
```

Probably not interested in `/var/cache` either ...

```
locate font | grep -v -e $HOME -e icons -e /man/ -e /locale/ -e /var/cache
```

etc.

Another use case I often have is searching for all versions of a program on my system.  `locate emacs` will spew out thousands of results, so I filter only for results where 'emacs' is in the basename:

```
locate emacs | egrep 'emacs[^/]+$'
```

D'oh, this still shows icons and man pages and whatnot.  So how about where the basename has no period after the emacs ...

```
locate emacs | egrep 'emacs[^/.]+$'
```

This is much better.

Remember, unlike `find`, `locate` is a database lookup; it doesn't consume any file system resources to search for results, so you're not sacrificing anything by generating lots of results and then filtering them with `grep`.